# SQL Multiple dynamic queries to one query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working in a SQL Server 2008 environment with SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

I have written 3 separate queries

**QUERY 1**

SQL query SUMS all the STOCK ON HAND from an `Inventories` table

```
SELECT      StockCode,
            Sum(QtyOnHand) AS 'SOH'
FROM        InvWarehouse
WHERE       StockCode NOT LIKE '%DEM%' AND StockCode NOT LIKE '%REF%' AND StockCode NOT LIKE 'Z%'
GROUP BY    InvWarehouse.StockCode
```

**QUERY 2**

This query looks at future orders from a Purchase Orders Table and dynamically  returns the next/following 12 months

```
DECLARE 
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@cols3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(YearMonth)
                  FROM 

                -- Selecting Using the Destinct --

                    (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(YEAR([OrderDueDate]) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH([OrderDueDate]) AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) AS YearMonth
                    FROM PorMasterHdr 
                    JOIN PorMasterDetail 
                    ON PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder = PorMasterHdr.PurchaseOrder
                    WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, OrderDueDate, DATEADD(m,12,GETDATE())) <= 12 ) sub

                    ORDER BY YearMonth

                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''),

   @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(YearMonth) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(YearMonth)
                  FROM 

                  -- Selecting Using the Destinct --

                    (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(YEAR([OrderDueDate]) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH([OrderDueDate]) AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) AS YearMonth
                    FROM PorMasterHdr
                    JOIN PorMasterDetail 
                    ON PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder = PorMasterHdr.PurchaseOrder
                    WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, OrderDueDate, DATEADD(m,12,GETDATE())) <= 12) sub

                    ORDER BY YearMonth 

                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')


SET @query = '
SELECT MStockCode, ' + @cols2 + ' 
FROM    (
        SELECT      MStockCode, 
                    MOrderQty, 
                    CAST(YEAR([OrderDueDate]) AS NVARCHAR(4))+RIGHT(''00''+CAST(MONTH([OrderDueDate]) AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) AS YearMonth
        FROM PorMasterHdr
        JOIN PorMasterDetail 
        ON PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder = PorMasterHdr.PurchaseOrder
        WHERE       MStockCode NOT LIKE ''%DEM%'' AND MStockCode NOT LIKE ''%REF%'' AND MStockCode NOT LIKE ''Z%''
        ) AS X  
PIVOT   (
        SUM(MOrderQty)
        FOR YearMonth in (' + @cols + ')
        ) AS PT'

EXECUTE (@query)
```

**QUERY 3**

This query looks at the past 12 month of sales data from a `Sales` table and dynamically returns the last/previous 12 months

```
DECLARE 
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@cols3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(YearMonth)
                  FROM 

                -- Selecting Using the Destinct --

                    (SELECT DISTINCT CAST([TrnYear] AS NVARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('00' + CAST([TrnMonth] AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) AS YearMonth
                    FROM ArTrnDetail
                    WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) <= 12 ) sub

                    ORDER BY YearMonth

                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''),

   @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(YearMonth) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(YearMonth)
                  FROM 

                  -- Selecting Using the Destinct --

                    (SELECT DISTINCT CAST([TrnYear] AS NVARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('00' + CAST([TrnMonth] AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) AS YearMonth
                    FROM ArTrnDetail
                    WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) <= 12) sub

                    ORDER BY YearMonth 

                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')


SET @query = '
SELECT StockCode, ' + @cols2 + ' 
FROM    (
        SELECT      StockCode, 
                    QtyInvoiced, 
                    CAST([TrnYear] AS NVARCHAR(4))+RIGHT(''00''+CAST([TrnMonth] AS NVARCHAR(2)),2) AS YearMonth
        FROM        ArTrnDetail
        WHERE       StockCode NOT LIKE ''%DEM%'' AND StockCode NOT LIKE ''%REF%'' AND StockCode NOT LIKE ''Z%''
        ) AS X  
PIVOT   (
        SUM(QtyInvoiced)
        FOR YearMonth in (' + @cols + ')
        ) AS PT'

EXECUTE (@query)
```

The results for each query are correct. Now how do I combine them into one query. So that they return

```
STOCKCODE     |   Past 12 Month Sales Per Month   |  Stock On Hand  |  Future Purchases

Helicopters   | 1  4  5  2  3  4  6  1  3  2  3  2|         15      |  2  3  5  4  6  7  8  4  3  2  8  5
Jam           | 2  5  6  4  8  5  8  5  7  2  1  2|         30      |  4  5  6  5  8  7  0  1  2  1  1  4
Frogs         | 2  3  2  4  8  5  4  6  8  2  1  3|          7      |  5  7  8  8  6  7  4  0  1  2  1  2
```

STOCK CODE for the above is the same information from the different tables eg. Helicopters in Inventory is the same as Helicopters in Purchase Orders.

Comment: you can create store procedure or create a SSRS report to produce the report above.

Comment: It's poor schema design to have separate columns for each year/month. This data should be in a separate table, with columns for the year and month, column(s) for the primary key/ID of the original table, and one column for the value. If you fix this, you can get the entire thing down to a single query that runs without any dynamic sql.

Comment: This is another reason why dynamic T-SQL should be avoided. Nevertheless, you may need to EXECUTE the results for those INTO temp tables so you can JOIN them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. Rewrite @query2 to result in two columns: StockCode and Sales. Instead of selecting each month as a seperate column, concatenate each month in a VARCHAR. You already wrote a variable for @cols for selecting the columns seperately. Keep that for pivoting. Write a variable (@SelSales) to concatenate the results for each month in a VARCHAR and use that in your selection for the Sales column.
2. Rewrite @query3 to result in two columns: StockCode and Purchases (similar to 1.)
3. Put your @query1 in a NVARCHAR(MAX) variable (the one selecting the stock).
4. Write a @query to combine them all.

TSQL outline for @query:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @query=N'
SELECT
  COALESCE(stock.StockCode,sales.StockCode,purchases.StockCode) AS StockCode,
  COALESCE(sales.Sales,''0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'') AS Sales,
  COALESCE(stock.SOH,0) AS Stock,
  COALESCE(purchases.Purchases,''0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'') AS Purchases
FROM
  ('+@query1+') AS stock
  FULL JOIN ('+@query2+') AS sales ON sales.StockCode=stock.StockCode
  FULL JOIN ('+@query3+') AS purchases ON purchases.StockCode=stock.StockCode';
EXEC(@query);
```